# Non-root user cannot run python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, permissions, redhat

I've install Python 2.7 on linux server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4). It works perfect, even with apache, with wsgi etc. But when I added new user and tried to run, it returned error:

```
[mynewuser@localhost ~]$ python2.7
python2.7: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What's the problem?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @Chris, ./configure  --enable-shared, make, make install.

Comment: can you create a group with read, write and execute permissions, add this user and add permissions to  python directory using chown/chgrp